# Transform 16 volt AC to 24 volt AC

Tags: transformer

I installed a Nest doorbell camera and now my doorbell chime buzzes.  Based on research, the problem is likely because the doorbell camera is using too much power.  A recommended solution was to increase the voltage (currently 16v).  I bought a new transformer, that can put out 24v and states it is compatible with most video doorbells.  My home is old, and I can't find the transformer in the basement or in any closet.  It may be in the attic, but there is 12 inches of insulation that was blown in, so will be a challenge to find.

Is there a transformer available that I could install by the doorbell chime to convert the 16v to 24v? Will this possibly solve my problem, or do I need to find the actual transformer and replace it?

Answer (score 1):

That will not solve your problem; the issue is that the parasitic current draw from the camera is passing enough current through the doorbell's coil that it's causing it to make a noise. Adding a transformer at the camera will not reduce the current draw since the power input to the camera remains the same (current through the doorbell might increase since the transformer isn't 100% efficient).

You could increase the voltage on the original loop, which it sounds like you were trying to do in the first place. This will reduce but not eliminate the parasitic current in the loop but the bigger issue is the doorbell might not be rated for the new voltage. Your best bet is to get a new doorbell entirely; I'm sure there are models out there that are made to deal with this exact issue. The Nest forums (if they exist) should have some good recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

What vir says.  However, it may suffice to use a bypass "resistor" that shunts across the chime, to allow the parasitic current to move around the chime.

I put resistor in quotes because it would be silly to use an actial resistor for that purpose in AC; a capacitor will do the same thing just fine and without making a bunch of heat.   I would recommend the Lutron LUT-MLC bypass capacitor made to solve this problem with 120V dimmers.   It is UL listed and packaged properly for direct installation, which a random UR rated component would not.